# read away certain signs from file-input

Tags: c++, operators, istream

So i'm building a program that reads a book, and counts the amount of times a specific word is appearing in it. However, if i try to read "word by word" with a whitespace delimiter it also is getting `"," "." and "double whitespaces"` into my result. How would i go about this problem? It guess it would be easier if i didnt have to use operators.

Code:

```
class Wordcounter
{
private:
    struct Data{
        string word;
        int n;
    } d;
    vector<Data> w;
public:
    friend istream&operator >>(istream&in, Wordcounter&Wordcounter){
        string junk;
        getline(in, Wordcounter.d.word, ' '); //Delimiter.


      /***************** I've tried something like this *********************
    if(Wordcounter.d.word.compare(".") != 0){
        getline(in, Wordcounter.d.word, ' ');
    } */


        return in;
    }
    friend ostream&operator << (ostream&out, Wordcounter&Wordcounter) {
        out << Wordcounter.d.word << endl;
        return out;
    }

    void read_file(string filename){
        ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open(filename);
        Wordcounter wc;
        while(myfile>>wc){
            wc.w.push_back(wc.d);
            cout << wc;
        }
        myfile.close();
    }



    Wordcounter(){
    }

    ~Wordcounter(){
    }
};
```

Comment: If I would do this I would still do it "word by word" using the normal input operator `>>`. Then simply strip leading and trailing non-alphabetic characters. Spacing is not a problem since the standard `>>` operator skips leading whitespace and stops at any space.

Comment: @RawN Either way, implementing Regex into an operator would still be quite difficult?

Comment: why is it a problem? Just count also the appearance of "." and "," and all the others and discard them from the results. What do you mean with "using operators"?

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you want count the frequencies of words I recommend you look into `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: @tobi303 since i'm "referencing/storing operators" (I think that's the correct term in english) i need to be able to make an all inclusive solution to this problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know, but using hashmaps wouldn't really help me here? :)

Comment: For frequencies/histograms? A map (of any kind) with the word as the key and the frequency as the data is definitely a possible solution. `++histogram[word]` is very easy to understand and handle.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude aaaah, yeah that's a good idea. So making the word "the key", and then iterating through the wordlist, and if a duplicate is found, add it to the second parameter in the map. map<string,int> ?

Comment: No need to iterate even. Just do as I showed in my previous comment and it will be handled automatically. If the word doesn't exist it will be created with a data-value of zero which then is incremented to one. If the word exists its data value will be incremented.